# Speeding up UDF that accesses data lake

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I am trying to write a UDF to enrich an IP column with geolocation information. The data that I want to use for the enrichment is stored in a data lake in the form of IP ranges to country. To read the file, I am using Java API, but I find this to be excruciatingly slow. Reading one million lines for instance takes upwards 2 minutes. Reading the full file takes several hours, which is surprisingly inefficient. Here is the code I use to read the file:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (SparkSession.builder
                     .master(...).getOrCreate())
sc = spark._sc
hadoopConf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
URI = sc._gateway.jvm.java.net.URI
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
BufferedReader = sc._gateway.jvm.java.io.BufferedReader
InputStreamReader = sc._gateway.jvm.java.io.InputStreamReader

datalake_file_system = '...'
account_name = '...'

fs = FileSystem.get(URI("abfss://{}@{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(datalake_file_system, account_name)), hadoopConf)

file_path = Path('...')
f = fs.open(file_path)

r = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(f))

while True:
    line = r.readLine()
    fields = line.split(',')
    if fields[0].startswith('start_ip'):
        continue
    # Load IP range to country mapping in a map
    ...
```

Is there a faster way to perform such operation?

The idea behind my UDF is to load the IP range/geo information in a map and then just perform a lookup in the UDF once the map is loaded in memory. There may be other more efficient ways of doing this in Spark. I would like to hear if there is a more typical way of doing something like this. The original information is in a table and I have written code to perform a join between tables, but since the merge involves IP ranges, a straight join is very inefficient. I have used bucketing and it did speed things up quite a bit, but I am trying to see if using a UDF would be even more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I have found to solve this problem is to create a Java UDF that performs lazy loading and lookups in the map.